# Problemas de Estado Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

Estou tentando pegar o id de um elemento clicado em uma lazylist e passar ele para a viewmodel para ser usado para carregar as informações completas desse item em uma nova tela

```
class InformacoesViewModel(): ViewModel( ) {


    private var _itemselecionado =  MutableStateFlow(1)
   
    val itemselecionado: StateFlow<Int> = _itemselecionado.asStateFlow()

    fun onItemClick(itemId: Int) {
        _itemselecionado.value = itemId
    }

}
```

na função onItemClick o id esta vindo correto, o problemas esta que a nova tela não esta pegando o item selecionado atualizado.

```
@Composable
fun Informacoes(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: InformacoesViewModel = viewModel(),
    onclickVolta: () -> Unit = {},
    ) {


    val uiId = viewModel.itemselecionado.collectAsState()
```

como informação complementar o elemento cliclavel chama duas função  primeira que pega o Id e a segunda e a que muda para a nova tela, oque sera que pode estar acontecendo?

codigo completo github https://github.com/brunocorbetta/UbatubaPraia

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.